# Virtual Laser pointer position in PowerPoint using COM

Tags: c#, com, add-in, powerpoint

There is a feature in PowerPoint that allow the presentator to fake a laser pointer to the screen by pressing "CTRL" + "Mouse Left Button" while being in a slide show (I'm using PowerPoint 2010, but I think this feature can be found in older versions). What I'm trying to do is to read position of laser while it's being shown (LIVE). I've created a C# add-in for PowerPoint which load every time I start PowerPoint and I'm using COM to access to the current presentation being shown. The problem I can't find any object in the PowerPoint COM model to get the laser positions and/or hook to an event to do so. So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve this using PowerPoint COM ?
2. If it's possible, how to? If not, can I achieve this in another way ?

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, it *is* a PowerPoint 2010 feature. It cannot be found in older versions of PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

The project here might help:

http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/mousemove_shape.html

It describes how to select and move shapes during a slide show; to do that, it works out the current pointer position.  That'd be the same as the laser pointer position, I expect, so the same method might work for you.